# How to print a single word out of a user input

Tags: java, string

How do i print out a single word out of a user input in java?
example:
user input:"We love mom she is the best".
the program suppose to print "mom" because of first and last chars are the same.
my code does not print anything at the end.
Here is my code:

```
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a Sentence");
        String input=s.nextLine();
        String builderString=" ";
        for(int i=0,j=0;i<input.length();i++){
            if(input.charAt(i)==' '){
                j=i+1; //upper the value of J if there is space (J will always check first char)
                if (input.charAt(j)==input.charAt(i)&&j<i) {//an if statement to check for match chars.
                        builderString=" "+input.charAt(i);// insert the char into a new string to print it in the console.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(builderString);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into detecting palindromes

Comment: You should use `input.split(' ')` to get an array of `String` of each word, it would make it way easier.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz OP never said palindrome. Just the first and last letter are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than parsing every letter of the string, you could split your input into an array of words and check each word individually.

You can keep your loop but you just have to check if the `chart at 0` is the same than the one at `word.length() - 1`

Here is a working example. Please note that i've remove the scanner part to make it work in the playground i'm using.

```
// This would be de equivalent of your scanner
String input = "We love mom she is the best";


String[] words = input.split(" ");
String output = "";
for(int i=0;i<words.length; i++){
   String currentWord = words[i];
   if(currentWord.charAt(0) == currentWord.charAt(currentWord.length() -1)) {
       output = currentWord;
    }
}   

System.out.println(output);
```

You also don't need your `j` variable no more.

You can test it out [here](https://code.sololearn.com/cGE0FvNhjcXh/#java)

Comment: Note that this assumes there's only a single word that satisfies the condition *or* that it's ok to get the last word that satisfies the condition in a sentence. (I'm not saying it's wrong, just pointing it out)